# Django Rest Framework - return list of Users or single User with ModelViewSet based on Permissions

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have seen several posts similar to this question, but none that solve my issue.

I am using Django Rest Framework's ModelViewSet. I have two views, a detail view and a list view.

**I want it so that if a superuser accesses my list view, he gets all the users. If a normal user accesses a list view, he can only see himself.**

**If a superuser accesses the detail view, he can view any user. If a normal user accesses a detail view that is not his, he gets an authentication error.**

I first attempted this with permissions only, but realized that with a query set of all for the list view the has_object_permission is not run allowing an authenticated non-superuser to view everyone. This is because object permissions are only run with a get command. I attempted to only override get_object, but get_object is not called for the list view so it made no difference. So I tried to override get_quertyset without get_objects, but this broke my detail view.

What I understand is that get_object is called first for a detail view, which then calls get_queryset if I don't override either of them. But if I override get_queryset, it breaks the normal functionality of my detail view and get_object (it doesn't filter based on primary key). There must be more going on behind the scenes than I see. There must be a way to write get_queryset to fix this that the normal Django version does that I'm not doing.

So below is what I implemented which works, but I don't understand why I have to override get_object. If I only override get_queryset, then the detail view is broken and returns all users when logged in as a superuser instead of one user filtered based on the primary key. Is there a way to override get_queryset without get_object to fix this behavior?

Views:

```
class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    permission_classes = (AllowPostAnyReadAuthenticatedUser,)

    def get_queryset(self):
        user = self.request.user
        if user.is_superuser:
            return User.objects.all()
        return User.objects.filter(username=user.username)

    def get_object(self):
        obj = get_object_or_404(User.objects.filter(id=self.kwargs["pk"]))
        self.check_object_permissions(self.request, obj)
        return obj
```

Permissions:

```
class AllowPostAnyReadAuthenticatedUser(permissions.BasePermission):

    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        # Allow anyone to register
        if request.method == "POST":
            return True
        # Must be authenticated to view
        else:
            return request.user and is_authenticated(request.user)

    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
        # Any view method requires you to be the user
        return obj.id == request.user.id or request.user.is_superuser
```

Serializer:

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'email', 'id', 'password')
        read_only_fields = ('id',)
        extra_kwargs = {
            'password': {'write_only': True}
        }
```

URLs:

```
userList = views.UserViewSet.as_view({
    'get': 'list',
    'post': 'create'
})

userDetail = views.UserViewSet.as_view({
    'get': 'retrieve',
    'put': 'update',
    'patch': 'partial_update',
    'delete': 'destroy'
})

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', userList, name='users'),
    url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)$', userDetail, name='user'),
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing this correctly!  You do not need to override the `get_object` method on your view though, [ModelViewSet checks your permissions in `get_object`](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/generics.py#L77).

Comment: Thanks for the response! If I don't override get_object, and I'm a superuser, the queryset, which is called by get_object, returns all my users instead of the one matching the primary key (as the override get_queryset will return all 4). I'm not sure how to make get_queryset act differently if it's a detail view vs. a list view (or if there is a pk listed vs not). So the detail_view gets 4 responses, which results in an error.